# How to check if error is tls handshake timeout in Go

Tags: http, go

I have the following code making a request to URL and checking for errors.

```
import "net/http"

response, err := http.Head("url")
```

How do check if the error is due to tls handshake timeout? I tried the following:

```
if err != nil {
    tlsError, ok := err.(http.tlsHandshakeTimeoutError)
    if ok {
        // handle the error
    }
}
```

But I cannot access the `http.tlsHandshakeTimeoutError` type because it is unexported. How else can I check for the error type in go?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes `tlsHandshakeTimeoutError` - is not exported and the only one 
possibility to check on this error is:

```
import "net/url"

// ....

if urlError,ok :=  err.(*url.Error)  ; ok {
    if urlError.Error() == "net/http: TLS handshake timeout" {
        // handle the error
    }
}
```

Here is open ticket with discussion about it:

https://github.com/golang/go/issues/15935

By the way `http` errors (and `tlsHandshakeTimeoutError` also) provide also:

```
type WithTimeout interface {
   Timeout() bool
}
```

You can use it for you check if you don't like string comparsion. [Here](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-go/blob/25b4a426b40c26c07c80af674b03db90b5bd4a60/transport/http2_client.go#L125) is example of isTemporary implementation from http2 package.

Comment: This is some really dumb design choice by Go authors. Does not surprise me though, given other similar quirks.

Comment: Actually this is not entirely correct, as I need to include the method and url in the string to compare, so the answer should be: `if err.Error() == "Head "+" net/http: TLS handshake tmieout" { // handle the error }"`.

Comment: You are right this error is wrapped by Do method I have updated my answer . But anyway the idea is the same - just string checking